# optimum resolution for a web layout when designing in Photoshop?

Tags: css, photoshop

First of all I want make clear that though I'm still learning CSS, I think I have fair understanding of it and especially liquid aspect of it and I also think that this is the way to go, however my question is about the graphic stage of web designing, so if I want to start a new project in Photoshop; what are the best page dimension should I use, keep in mind that I intend to use relative values when coding in CSS? and thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this should be moved to: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Kyle - It's not out of beta yet.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use 1300px x 2000px for the photoshop document.
Then I "sketch" up the 960px width wrapper. 
From there I start the creative process.

Take a look at http://photoshopetiquette.com/ for some more tips on web design in photoshop.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Most of the pages are being made to fit in 1024x768 (without a horizontal scroll) and the width of the page is about 950-980px. I can suggest you to start with 1200x1400 canvas in Photoshop and you can always resize it just go to Image -> Canvas Size